# Fill values for `data field` in Word 2010 using an external Excel data source

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, microsoft-word-2010

Let's say we have the staff list stored as an Excel spreadsheet file and we need to generate the document in formal formation or any other style to display those data using Word document.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest to do with a Mail Merge (even though you probably aren't mailing)  It just will create the correct fields.

Highlight the "range" that you want to use in word in the excel document and name it.
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-name-a-cell-or-range-in-excel-2010.html

Save and close your workbook.

Open the word document that you want to insert the names into.

Choose mailings from the menu bar and then "select recipients" button and then "use existing list"
Browse to the excel sheet you saved earlier and select it and click "open"
choose the range that you selected earlier.

Click on the "insert merge field" button to choose the column header for the information that you want displayed on the page.  it will insert `<<column head name>>` into the word document (this will later get filled with the names that you want.)

To get a a preview of the end result, click on "finish and merge" button and choose "edit individual documents" and then the "ALL" radio button and you will see how word inserts the person's name where you want it.

Comment: @G Koe So lovely. I got it working! Thanks a ton!